# change mapper to number of cores on each worker in hadoop 2.7.3

Tags: java, python, hadoop, mapreduce

By default, there can be two mapper for a job in hadoop 2.7.3. I have a cluster of 2 system with 4 core available on each. One is master and one is worker. Now I want to run 3 map tasks worker node. Can I do it? I am using hadoop streaming to run a job. So what argument should I set for this purpose. Also I want to set one input(line) to one mapper only. What should be the format of arguments. My current command that does not fullfil the job is

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar\
    -D mapred.output.compress=true \
    -D mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
    -files test.py   -mapper test.py    -reducer cat \
    -input /aws/input/sample.gz   -output /aws/output/test
```

Output shows that there is one maptask only

Answer (score 2):

Number of parallel running mappers is based on input splits and container resources.

Try `NLineInputFormat` so each line of input file go to its own mapper:

```
-inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.NLineInputFormat
```

Number of lines per mapper can be set with configuration param

```
-Dmapreduce.input.lineinputformat.linespermap=N
```

If you want the job to have only 3 mappers, you should set `N = file_lines / 3 + 1`

If you also want them to run in parallel, make sure there's enough RAM and CPU resources to run 3 map tasks at once. Usually it is configured in YARN xml files in setting `map container memory`. Remember Hadoop runs several auxiliary ecosystem processes like NameNode, DataNode, AppMaster, ResourceManager and others, that consume resources too.

Also I'm not sure about GZ file as input source, maybe you'll need to use plain text so NLineInputFormat could work.

Comment: Thanks, I said that I want three mapper per workers not overall. Actually, I want to use my workers cores completely.

Comment: @Shafiq the idea is the same anyway

Comment: Thanks, I am stuck at other point. I have posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561367/hadoop-2-7-3-analyze-gz-files-one-mapper-to-each-file

Comment: There are 5 files names only(one name per line). I have to test only that each mapper process one line successfully.

Comment: @Shafiq one text file with 5 rows, each line is a file name?

Comment: Actually I have to analyze commoncrawl data. They provide a file that contsist of all files on commoncrawl complete path. In order to process those compressed file, I have to assign one map to download that file and process it.

Comment: If you share your mail etc. then I can describe complete details ?

Comment: no, I understood what's your task. you should check AppMaster logs. usually there's a line describing input splits, e.g.  2017-01-09 20:59:13,176 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Input size for job job_1482225205308_0394 = 171798691840. Number of splits = 242